# Tesseract cross-compile aarch64 (arm64-v8a) error this header is for x86 only

Tags: c++, tesseract

I'm trying to cross compile Tesseract for arm64-v8a architecture settings are as follow.

```
set(ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_NAME aarch64-linux-android)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI arm64-v8a)
```

Compiler checks working as follow.

```
Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_MARCH_NATIVE
Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_MARCH_NATIVE - Failed
Performing Test HAVE_AVX
Performing Test HAVE_AVX - Success
Performing Test HAVE_AVX2
Performing Test HAVE_AVX2 - Success
Performing Test HAVE_FMA
Performing Test HAVE_FMA - Success
Performing Test HAVE_SSE4_1
Performing Test HAVE_SSE4_1 - Success
Performing Test HAVE_NEON
Performing Test HAVE_NEON - Success
```

and tesseract simddetect.cpp have following macros.

```
#if defined(HAVE_AVX) || defined(HAVE_AVX2) || defined(HAVE_FMA) || defined(HAVE_SSE4_1)
#define HAS_CPUID
#endif

#if defined(HAS_CPUID)
#if defined(__GNUC__)
# include <cpuid.h>
#elif defined(_WIN32)
# include <intrin.h>
#endif
#endif

#if defined(HAVE_NEON) && !defined(__aarch64__)
#ifdef ANDROID
#include <cpu-features.h>
#else
/* Assume linux */
#include <sys/auxv.h>
#include <asm/hwcap.h>
#endif
#endif 

SIMDDetect SIMDDetect::detector;

#if defined(__aarch64__)
// ARMv8 always has NEON.
bool SIMDDetect::neon_available_ = true;
#elif defined(HAVE_NEON)
// If true, then Neon has been detected.
bool SIMDDetect::neon_available_;
#else
// If true, then AVX has been detected.
bool SIMDDetect::avx_available_;
bool SIMDDetect::avx2_available_;
bool SIMDDetect::avx512F_available_;
bool SIMDDetect::avx512BW_available_;
// If true, then FMA has been detected.
bool SIMDDetect::fma_available_;
// If true, then SSe4.1 has been detected.
bool SIMDDetect::sse_available_;
#endif
```

compiler error

```
cpuid.h:11:2#error this header is for x86 only
```

Why tesseract include cpuid.h if it is only x86 file? what could be the fix for this error?

Answer (score 0):

Based on error message problem is seems to be in your toolchain:

1. You try to build 64bit arm version (`arm64-v8a`, `aarch64-linux-android`)
2. But **your compiler** provide only x86 only version of cpuid.h (#error this header is for x86 only)